How the code execution order works with await in js?
I'm trying to figure out how the code precedence and order is with presence of await, but it seems a little bit confusing, for instance I have code below:
const a = Promise.resolve(98);
const b = Promise.resolve(78);
const c = Promise.resolve(45);
const e = Promise.resolve(23);
setTimeout(() => console.log("hi8"));
const d = c.then(() => {
    console.log("hi9")
});
console.log("hi0");
async function lome() {
    console.log("hi1");
    await setTimeout(() => console.log("hi7"));
    console.log("hi2");
}
lome2();
lome();
console.log("hi3");

async function lome2() {
    console.log("hi10");
    await e.then(() => {
        console.log("hi11")
    });
    console.log("hi12");
}

setTimeout(() => console.log("hi4"));

b.then(() => console.log("hi6"));
    //output:hi0
    //hi10
    //hi1
    //hi3
    //hi9
    //hi11
    //hi7
    //hi6
    //hi12
    //hi2
    //hi8
    //hi4

so based on this code, we have sync codes, then promise handlers, and after that the code after await, then setTimeouts. so I said maybe the code after await has a precedence higher than setTimeouts and lower than promise handlers, then I confronted an issue in second example(check the code below):
const a = Promise.resolve(98);
const b = Promise.resolve(78);
const c = Promise.resolve(45);
const e = Promise.resolve(23);
setTimeout(() => console.log("hi8"));
const d = c.then(() => {
    console.log("hi9")
});
console.log("hi0");
async function lome() {
    console.log("hi1");
    await setTimeout(() => console.log("hi7"));
    console.log("hi2");
}
lome2();
lome();


async function lome2() {
    console.log("hi10");
    await e.then(() => {
        console.log("hi11")
    });
    console.log("hi12");
}

setTimeout(() => console.log("hi4"));
b.then(() => console.log("hi6"));
console.log("hi3");

//output:hi0
//hi10
//hi1
//hi3
//hi9
//hi11
//hi2
//hi6
//hi12
//hi8
//hi7
//hi4

in the second example first we have sync code, then we have promise handler in variable d then promise handler in function lome2, then instead of displaying promise handler result, stored in variable f which is hi6, first console displays hi2 which is code after await in function lome, so if code after awaits are supposed to have a lower precedence than promise handlers, so why in second example, it got displayed earlier than the last promise handler result?
so, I am confused right now and I'm wondering how  code execution precedence is with presence of await and promise handlers and setTimeouts?
p.n: the code is just a dummy code for practicing, don't peak on its application pls:)

The setTimeout() function does not return a Promise, so await will synthesize an already-resolved Promise with its value being the timer number returned from the call.

Note that Promise handlers happen during microtask resolution but setTimeout is deferred at least until the next full tick of the event loop. You also have a few other incorrect mental models. For instance the dot operator has a higher precedence than await so any method call will resolve before awaiting happens, not just .then.

As you can see, you are far from the first person to inquire about this topic

As a simple "rule" from my own experience: async/await is like a FIFO single-threaded queue: Calling an async puts that call/promise into a queue, and that queue is pulled from when you hit an await as a point to continue running. With the right setup, you'll notice you can't actually get two things truly running simultaneously in plain javascript: it's single-threaded, which gives you a lot of inherent safety from concurrency issues. Good for I/O bound tasks (common in JS), bad for CPU-bound ones (for which there's threads, or the environment-specific versions of it, or native apps)

I made a more simple exemple for understanding why some code execute before another.
  const fn1 = () => console.log('promise.then')
  const fnTimeout = () => console.log('timeout')

  const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('0')
    resolve(0)
    }
   )

   async function asyncFn(){
    console.log('fn')
    await promise
    console.log('after await')
   }

  console.log('1')

  promise.then(fn1)

  setTimeout(fnTimeout, 0)

  asyncFn()

  console.log('2')

Outputs for this code will be:
0
1
fn
2
promise.then
after await
timeout

Imagine a queue with block of code.
I will name block to visualize the queue.

The queue start with one block (A) containing all your code.

It will initialise fn1, fnTimeout, promise with your function in it.
It will log 0 then resolve the promise.
After this it will create  asyncFn.
Then log 1.
When it arrive to promise.then a new block will be create and put after the first block. So the queue is A -> B
First block continue and launch setTimeout which is not immediate and add a block few millisecond after.
In this interval asyncFn is run, so fn is log.
We have an await so a new block is added (C). The queue is now A -> B -> C.
Then we log 2 and block A is over.
setTimeout has probably added block D to the queue (because it has delay).


A is over so the queue is now B -> C -> D

B is now runnin, fn1 executed and promise.then log

Block B is over so block C is now running and after await is log.

Then block D is run and timeout is log.



tnx budd, but still there is no conclusion for this behaviour@edelir

This behaviour comes from javascript behavior. If you want more information you need to go deepdown  in javascript specification and it's processing behaviour.
